# Extra character(,) is added while using Textbox in spring

Tags: spring, html, spring-mvc

I am new to JSP and Spring. I want to insert a userID(U0005) using textbox in spring form but it is storing(,U0005). From where the "," is inserted?
The code I have written is:

/* In Register.jsp: */

```
    <c:url var="addAction" value="/libUsr/add"></c:url>
        <form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="libUsr">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <form:label path="id">
                                <spring:message text="ID" />
                            </form:label>
                        </td>
                        <td><form:input path="id" required="true" /></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
/*    
In UserController.java:

 */

        @RequestMapping(value= "/libUsr/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addLibUsr(@ModelAttribute("libUsr") LibUsr libUsr){
            libUsrDAO.saveOrUpdate(libUsr);
            return "redirect:/register";
        }

/*    
    In DAOImpl:
    Saving the data through DAOs
*/
        @Transactional
        public void saveOrUpdate(LibUsr libusr) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(libusr);
        }
```

Comment: did you check it?

Comment: did you figure out the problem? curious here with the problem/solution

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this tag:

```
<form:label path="id">
```

As you are adding the attribute *path* to one label, which wont store any value, spring try to get the value and returns empty,yourID.

Change the path attribute of your label to:

```
<form:label for="id">
    <spring:message text="ID" />
</form:label>
```

If you want to show the value of the id into that label use:

```
<label>${yourObject.id}</label>
```

or

```
<label th:value="${yourObject.id}"></label>
```

Path attribute is just for input, select, checkbox...not static values as label, span...